# fullcalendar events with data from database sent as Json

Tags: php, json, laravel, fullcalendar

I have a function in my controller that generates fullcalendar events generated from database that returns json in this format:

```
[{"allDay":"","id":17,"title":"Illness","start":"2015-06-05","end":"2015-06-05"}
,{"allDay":"","id":18,"title":"Illness","start":"2015-05-05","end":"2015-05-05"}]
```

I get this result fine when I go to `http://localhost/mysite/public/getlogs` but when I try to create events by doing:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //calendar options here              
                    events: 'getLogs'});
```

the get request this generates is this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/public/getLogs?start=2015-04-26&end=2015-06-07&_=1431949457792
```

and I don't get any new events in my calendar, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? do I need to add the start and end parameters to the endpoint that generates my json?

I'm using laravel so my route is just 'getLogs', I might need to add the parameters there but I'm not sure, I don't really have a lot of experience with php or web development in general to be honest

EDIT:
I already tried this in my routes.php but it didn't work:

```
Route::get('getlogs/{start}/{end}/{_}','CalendarController@getLogs');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appearantly I am an idiot:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //calendar options here              
                    events: 'getLogs'});
```

should be:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //calendar options here              
                    events: 'getlogs'});
```

Comment: For those who spent 5 minutes looking at the screen wondering what was different: lower case `L` on events.